# Unable to export entire data of Sitecore WFFM form into excel via form reports

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8.2

I am working on Sitecore 8.2 rev.161221 and Web Forms for Marketers 8.2 rev. 161129.

When I'm exporting a form data into excel using "Export form data to Excel" option inside Form Report it is giving me only 2-3 days data and not entire data from the beginning.

[image]

[image]

During wffm installation i run the script WFFM_Analytics.sql and i can see all the data of the form in reporting database WFFM tables but unable to view and export this entire from data inside Form Reports.

[image]

formsDataProvider is set to "analyticsFormsDataProvider" inside Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config

Why does it export only few data and not the entire data ?

Is there a way to get entire data of a form from SQL WFFM tables to the excel with "Export form data to Excel" option inside Form Report ?

Is there any time period setting to export form data of that time period only?

Is there a SQL query to just pass the formID parameter and will give me the entire data in correct organised way having form fields as columns and data as rows inside database ?

Comment: It looks like you tried to link an image or file unsuccessfully in your question.  Also, most of the questions above can't be answered without some more information or code.  Please post your code, the expected result, and the actual result.

Comment: I am trying to add image but it doesn't appear in the post. Am i missing something while adding image?